# In java, in this program it suddenly stops running properly at a certain point of code? but it compiles? any ideas what could be the issue?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

 public class task2 {
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    int a;
    int b;
    String y;
    String x;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter number A:");
    a = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nPlease enter number B:");
    b = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nLastly, enter A if you wish it to be the dividor and/or subtractor, or if you wish it to be B, please enter B :");             //stops running properly here...
    y=input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? Multiply (*), Divide (/), Subtract (-) or  Add   (+)? Please enter the symbol of which process you would like to have completed:");
    x=input.nextLine();


    if (y=="b"+"B") {

    if (x=="*") {
    System.out.println("\nThe product of these numbers is:" + a*b);}
    else 
    if (x=="/") {
    System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is:" + a/b);}
    else 
    if (x=="+") {
    System.out.println("\nThe sum of these numbers is:" + a+b);}
    else 
    if (x=="-") {
    System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is:" + (a-b));}}

    else 
    if (y=="a"+"A"){

    if (x=="*") {
    System.out.println("\nThe product of these numbers is:" + b*a);}
    else 
    if (x=="/") {
    System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is:" + b/a);}
    else 
    if (x=="+") {
    System.out.println("\nThe sum of these numbers is:" + b+a);}
    else 
    if (x=="-") {
    System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is:" + (b-a));}}
}
}
```

I dont know why it stops but where indicated by "//" the program suddenly stops letting me input information and does not continue the processes i want it to do. I wont bother explaining the program in detial because i believe it is fairly obvious from the code itself what i want to do. 
Thanks in adavance for all the help!

Comment: Working code: http://pastebin.com/K5MgyzLy

Comment: its not really homework.... its assignments i make myself do to learn programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
input.next();
```

not

```
input.nextLine();
```

Since nextLine() skips over the input and sets the scanner to the NEXT line and returns a string representation of what was skipped. Your program throws the errow because the NEXT line does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Your string comparisons are incorrect--you need to compare strings using the `equals()` method, like `x.equals("*")` in order for any of them to work. (This is a pretty common mistake, so even though it's homework, freebie :)

There's no loop, so it'll stop after the first time "through"; this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: nextLine returns a String... hasNextLine returns a boolean. However nextline skips over the input and sets the scanner to the NEXT line and returns a string representation of what was skipped.

Comment: alright so everything is cool until the final line... the calculation does not get outputted :S

Comment: @TheoLopezdeCastilla I'd probably ask a new question, then; can't see your code, but that whole "b"+"B" thing is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: No problem, to get output you need to change if (y=="b"+"B") to if (y.equals("b") || y.equals("B")) and the same for "a" and "A". mind accepting answer if it's valid