# Why won't the last output line of my Java program display?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In java, in this program it suddenly stops running properly at a certain point of code? but it compiles? any ideas what could be the issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869078/in-java-in-this-program-it-suddenly-stops-running-properly-at-a-certain-point-o)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class task2 {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        int a;
        int b;
        String y;
        String x;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter number A:");
        a = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter number B:");
        b = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nLastly, enter A if you wish it to be the dividor and/or subtractor, or if you wish it to be B, please enter B :");
        y=input.next();

        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? Multiply (*), Divide (/), Subtract (-) or Add (+)? Please enter the symbol of which process you would like to have completed:");
        x=input.next();

        if (y.equals("b"+"B")) {
            if (x.equals("*")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe product of these numbers is:" + (a*b));}
            else if (x.equals("/")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is:" + (a/b));}
            else if (x.equals("+")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe sum of these numbers is:" + (a+b));}
            else if (x.equals("-")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is:" + (a-b));
            }
        }

        else 
        if (y.equals("a"+"A")){
            if (x.equals("*")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe product of these numbers is:" + (b*a));}
            else if (x.equals("/")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is:" + (b/a));}
            else if (x.equals("+")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe sum of these numbers is:" + (b+a));}
            else if (x.equals("-")) {
                System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is:" + ((b-a)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A small program to do calculations on a set of two numbers. What I want is the user to enter the numbers and type of operation (including order) they want.
The result of the calculation does not display? any ideas? all help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please update your last question.

Comment: You need: `y.equals("b") || y.equals("B")` in place of `y.equals("b"+"B")`. `"b"+"B"` results in `"bB"`

Comment: Tip: If you are learning java. Do not post your questions so often. Spend some time debugging and understanding what is happening. Other wise you will never *understand* it.

Comment: Why are there limes in your program?

Comment: I'll have some pease please, with those limes!

Comment: One thing to make sure if to handle the final else case.  You should print an error message that Y was not a or b and you would have seen that message.  You also should handle the case where x is not a valid operator.

Comment: Also, you should consider reducing the code duplication and setting `first` and `second` based on the value of y.  Then your operator code would not have to be duplicated.  first * second, first / second, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing y and x against A+a and B+b
What you should do is :

`(y.equals("B") || y.equals("b"))`

Use the pipes `||` as an `OR` statement and not concatenating them with `+`

Here's the working code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SOScrap {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    int a;
    int b;
    String y;
    String x;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter number A:");
    a = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nPlease enter number B:");
    b = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nLastly, enter A if you wish it to be the dividor and/or subtractor, or if you wish it to be B, please enter B :");
    y=input.next();

    System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? Multiply (*), Divide (/), Subtract (-) or Add (+)? Please enter the symbol of which process you would like to have completed:");
    x=input.next();


    if (y.equals("B") || y.equals("b")) {

    if (    x.equals("*")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe product of these numbers is:" + (a*b));}
    else
    if (x.equals("/")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is:" + (a/b));}
    else
    if (x.equals("+")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe sum of these numbers is:" + (a+b));}
    else
    if (x.equals("-")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is:" + (a-b));}}
    else{
    if (y.equals("A") || y.equals("a")){

    if (x.equals("*")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe product of these numbers is:" + (b*a));}
    else
    if (x.equals("/")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe quotient of these numbers is:" + (b/a));}
    else
    if (x.equals("+")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe sum of these numbers is:" + (b+a));}
    else
    if (x.equals("-")) {
    System.out.println("\nThe difference of these numbers is:" + ((b-a)));}}}
           }}
```

Comment: Nice answer dude.  +1 Be careful about your indenting.  Also, consider only showing the code for the fixed lines instead of all lines.